# Is there an easier/shorter way to get geographic coordinates from GoogleMaps?

Tags: php, google-maps

I'm currently using the following method to get coordinates from GoogleMaps.
Can I possibly write this shorter/more efficient?

**EDIT 21.06.2013**

As of now the old [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) is off. This is my modified code that works with the most recent version. I've updated this post, if someone stumbles over it and finds it useful.

```
public function getGeographicCoordinatesFromGoogle()
{
    // create address string
    $value = $this->address_line_1 . ' ' .
             $this->postal_code . ' ' .
             $this->city . ' ' .
             $this->country;
    $value = preg_replace('!\s+!', '+', $value);

    // create request
    $request = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=' .
               $value . '&sensor=false';

    // get value from xml request
    $xml = file_get_contents($request);
    $doc = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    @$doc->loadXML($xml);

    // fetch result
    $result = $doc->getElementsByTagName('lat')->item(0)->nodeValue . ',' .
              $doc->getElementsByTagName('lng')->item(0)->nodeValue;

    // check result
    if (!preg_match('/(-?\d+\.\d+),(-?\d+\.\d+)/', $result) ) {
        $result = null;
    }
    // assign value
    $this->setGeographicCoordinates($result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use json instead of xml. json is newer, lightweight and object orientated.

Comment: +1 Yeah, I saw the JSON-support today when I switched to the new API. I think the old one didn't support it and I think I'll go with that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you to use http_build_query() instead of trying to build the SearchQuery with Regex. There are other chars which need to be escaped.

This is a quite long method. Maybe it would make sense to have one Class which only handles the communication with GoogleMaps (Class GeoBackend with methods getGeoDataForAddress(), which returns a GeoData-Object, which could be asked for Cordinates etc.)